# Target for UIButton created through loop not working on Button at 0 index

Tags: ios, swift

I have create 2 buttons using loop. Also I have addTarget for them in same loop. But target for button at index 0 is never called, while it is called everytime for button at index 1. Here is my code

```
let buttonTitles = ["GIFs","Stickers"]
let enumberatedTitles = buttonTitles.enumerated()
var originX: CGFloat = 2.5
var buttonWidth = 100
self.containerView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * buttonWidth + 5
self.containerView.frame.size.height = 50
self.containerView.center.x = self.frame.width/2
self.containerView.center.y = self.frame.height/2
for(index,item) in enumberatedTitles {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.frame.origin.x = originX
    button.frame.origin.y = 2.5
    button.frame.size.width = buttonWidth
    button.frame.size.height = 45
    button.tag = index
    button.accessibilityHint = item
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.containerView.addSubview(button)
    originX += longestLabelWidth
}
```

Target for button

```
@objc private func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if let touchedButton = self.containerView.subviews.first(where: {
        $0.tag == sender.tag
    }) {
        self.selectedView.frame = touchedButton.frame
    }
}
```

Comment: The tag value defaults to 0. So I suspect your first where logic is not doing what you expect it to.

Comment: @DanielStorm I also tried with setting tag as index+1, but still not working.